# Duplicate assets after deployment of app in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I'm very new with rails development and deployment using Heroku.

So recently I found that some JavaScript files that seems to be duplicated. For example I made a javascript function in one file (sample.js), then I erased this file, and I put the function inside of application.js.

Under my test development, it works perfect. But then when I commit the changes to heroku, I end up having the same function twice!

The javascript files are under the folder /app/assets/javascripts/

So how can I tell heroku to remove the duplicate files?

Am I missing some step before sending new version of my app to heroku?

Any help will be greatly appreciated

ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [i686-linux]
Rails 3.1.0

Comment: When you committed to heroku, did you ```git rm sample.js```?

Comment: Hi nathancahill, thanks for your reply! When I commited the changes to heroku I ran this set of commands
[git add -f *],
[git commit -m "changing js function for menu"],
[git push heroku main]


Now the commit step added the following line in the HEAD file
deleted:    app/assets/javascripts/sample.js

So I don't know if this change where efectively taken by Heroku??

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only deleting files from the repo when you use the `git rm` command. Even if you delete the actual file, it's still in the repo, and won't be changed by the `git add -f *` command (which only adds changed files).

You should be able to remove the file from heroku by running these commands:

```
$ git rm app/assets/javascripts/sample.js
$ git commit -m 'your commit message'
$ git push heroku master
```

Comment: indeed that did the job! 

Your answer point me in the right direction, in the sense that it wasn't heroku's fault, it was the way I was using the git commands.